# Error handling of Django modal Bootstrap form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I have created two forms in Django: one for registering a new user and one for logging-in the user.
They work fine, but I'd like to implement an Ajax control: if there is an error, the page doesn't reload, but instead the modal window stays there and shows the error.

Here's my **view**

```
def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()

            registered = True

            return render(request, 'blog/registered.html')

        else:
            print user_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'user_form': user_form})

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = CustomLoginForm(request.POST)
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password2')

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your Pin a Voyage account is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(email, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied. Get back to the <a href=\"/\">homepage</a>.")
    else:
        login_form = CustomLoginForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'login_form': login_form})
```

The **forms**

```
@parsleyfy
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given email and password.
    """

    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'E-Mail',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'First name',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    second_name = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Last name',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))

    password2 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Password confirmation (enter the same password as above, for verification)',
            'equalto': "new_password1",
            'error-message': "Your passwords do not match.",
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "second_name",)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


@parsleyfy
class CustomLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that login a user.
    """

    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(
        attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'E-Mail',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
    ))

    password2 = forms.CharField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {
            'placeholder': 'Password',
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',)
```

And this is the **template**

```
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <a id="login_btn" class="btn_sub_log top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></a>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="sign-up">Login with Pin a Voyage</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form data-parsley-validate method="post" action="/login/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if next %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                    {% endif %}

                    {{ login_form.as_p }}

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <a id="subscribe_btn" class="btn_sub_log"><h2 class="top-menu sign-up">Sign up!</h2></a>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="subscribe_modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="sign-up">Register with Pin a Voyage</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form data-parsley-validate id="user_form" method="post" action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {{ user_form.as_p }}

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What's the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you'd need to use JavaScript to to validate the form before it gets sent to the server.  I recommend the [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/) library; you can use the [widget attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) to add the correct classes and attrs to the form, then include the parsley script, and that is I believe the simplest way given your current code to add the validation to the front end.